# How to transfer my ships to a new computer?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I recently built a new PC, and transferred all of my games to it. However, when I transferred FTL to my new computer, I found that all the ships that I had unlocked were now gone. I have a non-steam copy bought directly from the website, so I simply copied the entire folder from my old computer to my new one, thinking that it would all come along. This does not seem to be the case, however.

How do I transfer all of my unlocked ships to my new computer, without having to unlock them again?

Comment: This is what makes Steam Cloud a really nice feature for games to have.  Needing to backup these things ourselves is just asking for data loss.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FTL save data on Windows Vista and above is located at `C:\Users\{your user name}\Documents\my games\fasterthanlight`.
To move your save files you need to transfer the `fasterthanlight` folder to your new PC in your `documents\my games` directory.

Comment: Yup, just figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

Ship data is stored in your save data directory.  The directory will change whether you're on windows or mac, but if you use steam finding local files is easier.

Comment: You're not wrong, altough I don't know if FTL has its save files in same place as game executables. But either way, additional details would greatly improve your answer.